# How do I use the default style for widget?

Tags: themes, sidebar

I added the twitter feed sidebar widget on my website, as seen below. but the theme makes the text / background unreadable. How do i use the default style for it / prevent the theme from changing it?

This is the code for the sidebar.php, also, I have no basic knowledge of coding. so the below makes zero sense to me, i tried searching for a solution, i found nothing.

sidebar.php

```
<aside class="edgtf-sidebar">
    <?php
        $edgtf_sidebar = overworld_edge_get_sidebar();
        
        if ( is_active_sidebar( $edgtf_sidebar ) ) {
            dynamic_sidebar( $edgtf_sidebar );
        }
    ?>
</aside>
```

[image]

This is the widget:

[image]

Comment: There isn't a way to just make a theme not apply styles to a specific widget, or to just use 'default styles' from the widget. That's just not how CSS works. The only solution is to add your own CSS to address the issues, or find a plugin that works better with your theme.

Comment: noted, thank you.